# Applying Scrolling effect to one type of Cell in Multiple cell condition

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

Okay, so I have 2 type of cells and they are being loaded fine, but for one type of cell I would like to apply some type of effect as user scroll. I can have one type of cell and apply the effect to it and it works fine, but when I include the second type of cell, the app crash with an error.

**Scrolling Function:**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offsetY = self.tableView.contentOffset.y
    for cell in self.tableView.visibleCells as! [NormalPostTableViewCell] {
        let x = cell.postPhoto.frame.origin.x
        let w = cell.postPhoto.bounds.width
        let h = cell.postPhoto.bounds.height
        let y = ((offsetY - cell.frame.origin.y) / h) * 35
        cell.postPhoto.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)
    }
}
```

**Cell classes:** `NormalPostTableViewCell` & `PostsTableViewCell`

**Error:**
The error happen as soon as I hit different type of cell.

> fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element
>   type

Comment: You have forced a downcast to `[NormalPostTableViewCell]` yet you have said that you have two different types of cell - so you get the pretty self explanatory exception message.  If you make one of your cells a subclass of the other then you can use the superclass in the cast.

Comment: @Paulw11 can you please in codes?

Comment: I presume that both of your cells subclass UITableViewCell - you could change so that one does and the other subclasses the first. Or you can change your array cast to `[UITableViewCell]`

Comment: If I do, I get an error: `UITableViewCell' does not have a member named 'postPhoto' `

Comment: They are subclass `'class NormalPostTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{}'`

Comment: This is why you really need to subclass one cell from the other - then you can use the superclass and both will have a `postPhoto` - perhaps if you add the class definitions of both cells to your question I can help more

Comment: I have create a subclass from NormalPostTableViewCell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84748/discussion-between-brian-s-and-paulw11).